# Unable to Create New Incidents in Dynamics CRM with Java and Axis2

Tags: java, apache-axis, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

So I've been working on trying to figure this out, oddly when I ran it one machine I got a generic Axis Fault with no description, but now on another machine I'm getting a different error message, but I'm still stuck. Basically I'm just trying to do what I thought would be a fairly trivial task of creating a new incident in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 via a web services call.

I started by downloading the XML from http://hostname/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmService.asmx and generating code from it using Axis2. Anyway, here's my program, any help would be greatly appreciated, as I've been stuck on this for way longer than I thought I'd be and I'm really out of ideas here.

```
    public class TestCRM {  

    private static String endpointURL = "http://theHost/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmService.asmx";  
    private static String userName = "myUserNameHere";  
    private static String password = "myPasswordHere";  
    private static String host = "theHostname";  
    private static int port = 80;  
    private static String domain = "theDomain";
    private static String orgName = "theOrganization";

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        CrmServiceStub stub;  
        try {  
            stub = new CrmServiceStub(endpointURL);  
            setOptions(stub._getServiceClient().getOptions());  

            RetrieveMultipleDocument rmd = RetrieveMultipleDocument.Factory.newInstance();  
            com.microsoft.schemas.crm._2007.webservices.RetrieveMultipleDocument.RetrieveMultiple rm = com.microsoft.schemas.crm._2007.webservices.RetrieveMultipleDocument.RetrieveMultiple.Factory.newInstance();

            QueryExpression query = QueryExpression.Factory.newInstance();  
            query.setColumnSet(AllColumns.Factory.newInstance());  
            query.setEntityName(EntityName.INCIDENT.toString());    

            rm.setQuery(query);  
            rmd.setRetrieveMultiple(rm);

            TargetCreateIncident tinc = TargetCreateIncident.Factory.newInstance();
            Incident inc = tinc.addNewIncident();
            inc.setDescription("This is a test of ticket creation through a web services call.");

            CreateDocument cd = CreateDocument.Factory.newInstance();
            Create create = Create.Factory.newInstance();
            create.setEntity(inc);

            cd.setCreate(create);

            Incident test = (Incident)cd.getCreate().getEntity();

            CrmAuthenticationTokenDocument catd = CrmAuthenticationTokenDocument.Factory.newInstance();  
            CrmAuthenticationToken token = CrmAuthenticationToken.Factory.newInstance(); 
            token.setAuthenticationType(0);     
            token.setOrganizationName(orgName);  
            catd.setCrmAuthenticationToken(token);          

            //The two printlns below spit back XML that looks okay to me?
            System.out.println(cd); 
            System.out.println(catd);
            /* stuff that doesn't work */   
            CreateResponseDocument crd = stub.create(cd, catd, null, null); //this line throws the error
            CreateResponse cr = crd.getCreateResponse();
            System.out.println("create result: " + cr.getCreateResult());
            /* End stuff that doesn't work */

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            boolean fetchNext = true;  
            while(fetchNext){  
                RetrieveMultipleResponseDocument rmrd = stub.retrieveMultiple(rmd,  catd, null, null);
                //This retrieve using the CRMAuthenticationToken catd works just fine

                RetrieveMultipleResponse rmr = rmrd.getRetrieveMultipleResponse();  
                BusinessEntityCollection bec = rmr.getRetrieveMultipleResult();  

                String pagingCookie = bec.getPagingCookie();  
                fetchNext = bec.getMoreRecords();  

                ArrayOfBusinessEntity aobe = bec.getBusinessEntities();  
                BusinessEntity[] myEntitiesAtLast = aobe.getBusinessEntityArray();  

                for(int i=0; i<myEntitiesAtLast.length; i++){  
                    //cast to whatever you asked for...  
                    Incident myEntity = (Incident) myEntitiesAtLast[i];  
                    System.out.println("["+(i+1)+"]: " + myEntity);
                }  
            }  
        }   
        catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  

    private static void setOptions(Options options){  
        HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();  

        List authSchemes = new ArrayList();  
        authSchemes.add(HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator.NTLM);   
        auth.setAuthSchemes(authSchemes);   

        auth.setUsername(userName);
        auth.setPassword(password);  
        auth.setHost(host);  
        auth.setPort(port);  
        auth.setDomain(domain);  
        auth.setPreemptiveAuthentication(false);  
        options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);  
        options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, "true");  
    }
}
```

Also, here's the error message I receive:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'S' (code 83) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:123)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:354)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at com.spanlink.crm.dynamics4.webservice.CrmServiceStub.create(CrmServiceStub.java:618)
    at com.spanlink.crm.dynamics4.runtime.TestCRM.main(TestCRM.java:82)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'S' (code 83) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:260)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:161)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.getSOAPBuilder(BuilderUtil.java:682)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:215)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:145)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:108)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'S' (code 83) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:623)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2047)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1069)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:60)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.SafeXMLStreamReader.next(SafeXMLStreamReader.java:183)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:597)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:172)
    ... 13 more
```

Edit: Ah, I think maybe I'm on to something. I used wireshark to see what was going on, and it looks like that 'S' is from a server response. Sniffing the traffic, it looks like the problem is, "Server was unable to process request. ---> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> You should specify a parent contact or account.\r\n"

I'll leave this unanswered as of now, cause I technically don't have it working yet, but at least I know what's going on now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work, just needed to add a parent account.

Comment: have you implemented MS CRM. I'm facing an problem while following the reference provided at here http://javamscrm.codeplex.com/. Can you please help to implement crm over java

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you got this working. When CRM throws exceptions, first thing to check is the CRM trace logs. CRM provides a pretty good description of what went wrong. This helps to narrow down your investigation considerably.

More info on enabling trace on the server:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490